# MongoDB slow fetching using MongoDB C# driver 2.13

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I'm trying to fetch **40000-50000** documents from the MongoDB collection using the MongoDB c# driver.
It's taking more than **1 min** to fetch documents(40000 docs) using the find().toList() method

But we have a requirement to fetch all documents from the collection in **2-3 seconds**.

some info about my MongoDB database

Average document size is **58KB** and collection contains **50000** documents

Note - The task is to fetch all documents in 2-3 seconds
// collection.find(new bsondocument()).toList();

Does anyone have a solution for the above task?

thanks in advance.

Comment: There are a lot factors that can affect it like indexes, what serializer you're using, your setup, network and etc.
I would start with checking how long this query takes in the mongo shell. By this you will exclude any driver affection. If it's still close to what you see now, you will need to look at indexes that you have, your mongo setup and network

Comment: @dododo thanks for replay. In mongo shell query execution is very fast also I have added indexes on fields ..also I have checked whether the query uses added indexes or not. Any others suggestions from our side

Comment: just to confirm, when you say in the shell it works very quick, you mean that you execute *exactly* the same query for *exactly* the same collection with *exactly* the same number of result records(ie batchSize with default value in the shell 20 is not involved) in *exactly* the same environment? If so, what time it takes?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.